# Pantheon DE in other distributions?

Tags: pantheon

I like Pantheon, but I do not like Ubuntu. I will use Pantheon if it can be installed on other Linux systems. Now Pantheon is tied to Ubuntu and it's sad. Ported hard and does not work ... Pantheon will be untied from Ubuntu for porting to other distributions? When? On Archlinux it is ported since 2012 ...

Answer (score 2):

From what I've recently read, Pantheon is able to be installed not only on top of Arch but also Fedora and OpenSUSE with a certain level of success.

The one thing to keep in mind is, that in some cases, the results of installing Pantheon on top of other distros may not give an end-user experience at the same level as using elementary OS. Until a distro like Antergos (Arch based) or Gecko Linux (OpenSUSE based) create an official or community spin, I personally, would stay away. Finding support within a user forum of a distro that does not officially support Pantheon or support it via a community release may prove to be difficult when the time to troubleshoot issues arrives.

If you're thinking of moving forward, doing an internet search using 'Pantheon Desktop Environment' plus the distro of your choice will get you moving in the right direction.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Users will, I'm sure. Over time, support will appear. But these steps will come with time and will be useless without porting. I think that other DE also went through this. And now they can be installed in any distribution. Pantheon will not be able to jump until he lets go of Ubuntu.